# Takes control of system wide(for all apps) usage of Microphone

Tags: android, hardware, microphone

For Microphone disabling, I came across a way to mute the Microphone. But I am not sure if this would work even if my app is not running. I mean if I could write, or rather over-write some system settings to "BLOCK" the Microphone. Please let me know if this is possible.

Ultimately, I want to control the Microphone of the device from my App. Having the Microphone Disabled from my App, no application should be able to use it. I came across numerous applications on play store that can do this, but could not find a stepping stone to this task.

I guess folks around might have some inputs or directions for me on this task.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 methods to control/disable the mic

1. [setMicrophoneMute(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setMicrophoneMute(boolean))
2. Continuously record the mic stream in service :) Like [THIS APP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bettertomorrowapps.microphoneblockfree&hl=en) is doing

   ```
         this.b = new MediaRecorder();
         this.b.setAudioSource(5);
         this.b.setOutputFormat(1);
         this.b.setAudioEncoder(1);
         this.b.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
         this.b.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
   ```

Comment: Setting Mic to Mute can be ReSet by other apps, they can detect/check if the Mic is Muted and if it is, it can be Un-Muted from the other apps. I do not confirm on this, but this must be possible. Is it?

Comment: Record the stream in a service will work for sure. But I guess there must be a bit less aggressive way of doing this.

Comment: Its my pleasure to dig in these kind of things  :)

Comment: I know only these ways ;)